# how to force evaluation of macros in a #define for the c-preprocessor

Tags: c-preprocessor

I would like to make change the way some code works by redefining a macro using the old value of the macro. However, due to the way macros seem to be evaluated, it doesn't work for me. What I would like is for immediate evaluation of the macro in the `#define`, so that something like

```
#define A B
```

defines `A` to be the value of `B` at the time of the `#define`, and not be affected by redefinitions of `B` at a later time.

This example works:

```
// in a header somewhere, can't change this
#define A 1


// wrapper code to replace the number with a run-time expression
#define OLD_A 1
#define NEW_A 42
#undef A
bool flag = false;
#define A  ( flag ? NEW_A : OLD_A)


// user code, don't want to change this
//

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  flag = false;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
  flag = true;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
}
```

Output (as intended):

```
1$ ./cpptest
A is 1
A is 42
```

However, if I change the definition of `OLD_A` to `A`, then it doesn't compile.

```
// in a header somewhere, can't change this
#define A 1


// wrapper code to replace the number with a run-time expression
#define OLD_A A  /// <------ here
#define NEW_A 42
#undef A
bool flag = false;
#define A  ( flag ? NEW_A : OLD_A)


// user code, don't want to change this
//

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  flag = false;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
  flag = true;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
}
```

Build fails:

```
$ make cpptest
icpc     cpptest.cpp   -o cpptest
cpptest.cpp(19): error: identifier "A" is undefined
    printf("A is %s\n",A);
                       ^
```

I understand this is a horrible way to design code to be maintainable, but this is a patch to a one-off old release, and in this case it makes sense to me, as it requires less changes to other working code.

Answer (score 1):

This answer only deals with the "Why does it not work?" part of the question.
The part on "How to?" probably needs you to drop the intention to use the old definition of the macro; because I consider that the root of the problem.

Preprocessor macros work differently from variables.
Variables have a value and do not care how they got it.
Preprocessor macros are expanded to their definition,
not the value of the definition at the time of defining.

So what happens in your problematic case is:

```
// in a header somewhere, can't change this
#define A 1
```

"A" being defined to "1", which gets ignored later.

```
// wrapper code to replace the number with a run-time expression
#define OLD_A A  /// <------ here
```

"OLD_A" being defined to "A", which **currently would** expand, in two steps, to "1".

```
#define NEW_A 42
#undef A
```

"A" being undefined, preprocessor stops knowing about it being "1".

```
bool flag = false;
#define A  ( flag ? NEW_A : OLD_A)
```

"A" being defined to "( flag ? NEW_A : OLD_A)"
which currently would expand to "( flag ? NEW_A : A)",
of which "A" is (in one way or another) not recursively expanded (which would not help either).

```
// user code, don't want to change this

#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
  flag = false;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
```

Compiler sees:  'printf("A is %d\n",( flag ? NEW_A : A));'.

```
  flag = true;
  printf("A is %d\n",A);
```

Compiler sees:  'printf("A is %d\n",( flag ? NEW_A : A));'.

```
}
```

Did you try to pre-process-only the file, instead of compiling?
It results in support of my interpretation.
(Using gcc, after I deleted the include, which is not needed for this experiment; also deleting some unhelpful lines from the output):
`MinGW\bin\gcc -E cpptest.cpp`

```
bool flag = false;

main()
{
  flag = false;
  printf("A is %d\n",( flag ? 42 : A));
  flag = true;
  printf("A is %d\n",( flag ? 42 : A));
}
```

You are right about the "horrible design", at least in my opinion. But in reality, sometimes good design is prevented by outside circumstances. And those outside circumstances often end in "€/$/currency of your choice".
In this case the circumstances take a detour via "code with ancient and very good test status should not be changed". Which is a good reason.
Maybe you can convince decision makers that the edit (which would replace the current fully static macro "A==1" by something dynamic) is not heeding that requirement either. The test status (probably based, among other things, on code coverage) would be pretty much void after this.